# Creating a online webpage designer using jquery, is it hard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create an online web page editor using jquery.

How complicated is this type of feature? (yes I know its hard to answer this)

From what I can tell, you are simply referencing the various elements on the page and when a user selects a color in a colormap, you simply then cycle through the elements on the page that match a particular set of id's or classes and modify them.

I would also need to use jQuery live as new elements in the DOM will be added/removed.

Am I making it easier than it is?

Comment: The answer to this question ("how complicated is this") depends entirely on how flexible you want it to be. How about deciding that first. If all you want is changing the colors for some elements, that's child's play. A full-page editor is a much more formidable task.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to figure out how jqueryui theme roller bookmarklet works:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/